The power of Harrison's order
Due to Joseph Harrison we know that there exists a recursive linear order such that every recursive ordinal is isomorphic to an initial segment of this order. What is the  "logical power" of this theorem? More specifically, if we denote this theorem by $H$, what can we say about $\mathrm{ACA}_0 + H$ ? Is this theory much stronger than $\mathrm{ACA}_0$? What is its proof theoretic ordinal?

Below, I'll put sentences in a separate font to distinguish them from sets. I've also added a superscript-$0$ to indicate the "lightface" aspect of the principles involved; note that the subscript-$0$ in e.g. $\mathsf{ATR}_0$ refers to induction, not computability-theoretic complexity.

I claim that $\mathsf{H}^0$ implies, over $\mathsf{ACA}_0$, the principle $\mathsf{J}^0$ = "For every computable well-ordering $L$, there is a (unique) jump hierarchy along $L$" (basically, $\emptyset^{(L)}$ exists). This principle can be thought of as the "lightface version" of $\mathsf{ATR}_0$.
If $\mathsf{J}^0$ fails, then there are computable well-orderings $A,B$ neither of which embeds into the other (this is basically just observing that the proof of the reversal $\mathsf{CWO\rightarrow ATR_0}$ "goes through computably"). But then there can be no linear order - computable or otherwise - into which both $A$ and $B$ embed as initial segments. And so $\mathsf{H}^0$ fails as well.

What about the converse? Well, I suspect that this fails, actually, even for $\omega$-models. The basic idea is to start with $\mathsf{HYP}$ (which satisfies $\mathsf{ACA_0}$ but not $\mathsf{J}^0$) and progressively add jump hierarchies along the apparent well-orderings without $(i)$ adding descending sequences along any Harrison orders or $(ii)$ ever putting a single Harrison ordering "on top" with respect to initial segment embeddings. The details of this aren't clear to me but it seems possible. That said, note that the "boldface" versions of $\mathsf{H}^0$ and $\mathsf{J}^0$ are each just $\mathsf{ATR}_0$, so the previous paragraph does still decently pin down the strength of $\mathsf{H}^0$.

A nice argument, the principle $\mathrm{J}^0$ seems indeed very relevant. As for the converse, if we are modest and want only to show that $\mathrm{H}^0$ is not in $\mathrm{ACA}_0$, then it seems that the argument with $\mathrm{HYP}$  does the job. For this "modest" claim, can we make the argument purely model-theoretic? It seems that we only need to find in $\mathrm{HYP}$ a pair of computable well orderings that are incomparable.

@A1997 It's not hard (folklore I think) to use Barwise compactness to produce a pair of computable linear orders $A,B$ such that neither has a hyperarithmetic descending sequence and neither hyperarithmetically embeds (as an initial segment or otherwise) into the other. Consequently, $\mathsf{HYP}$ does not satisfy $\mathsf{H}^0$.

But we don't need this. If all we want is $\mathsf{ACA}_0\not\vdash\mathsf{H}^0$, we can use $\mathsf{J}^0$: the $\omega$-\model $\mathsf{ARITH}$ of $\mathsf{ACA_0}$ doesn't satisfy $\mathsf{J}^0$ (so by my answer, doesn't satisfy $\mathsf{H}^0$) since e.g. $\emptyset^{(\omega)}$ is not arithmetic.
